# is it possible to adjust the height of the container to the height of the image that contains?

Tags: html, css

I have a header, and the width is set to 100% because I want that the image adjust to the size of the browser. However, I want to adjust the height of the conteiner to the height of the image to see the image completly.

I am using this code in my css file:

```
background-image: url('http://...');
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

I use the size auto in the height to respect the ratio of the image.

I know that normally the content is adjust to the size of the container, but in the case of the height, I would like to adjust the height of the container according to the element that contains. Is it possible?

Thanks so much.

Comment: So you have no actual image _element_ within the container, but are using only a _background_-image? Then there is no way to make the container automatically as high as that background-image.

Comment: Is it different background than image in a container? how can I set the image instead of the background? for me no matter if I use an image instead of a background.

Comment: If you don’t know how to embed an image in HTML … then please go learn some basics.

Comment: `<img src="..." alt="" style="width:100%" />` Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: [This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207639/200902)

Just add an image element in your div - and the div will by default take the height of the img

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rPn9z/1/)**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
</div>
```